# Deploying different service-account-credentials.json file to different cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts, firebase-cli

Working on creating two separate Firebase Projects, one as a dev environment and the other as our production environment so as to simulate the real thing when testing new features.

Whenever I need to deploy to the cloud functions to either of the projects I do the following things:

1. Copy and paste the correct service account credentials into the service-account-credentials.json file
2. Select respective project's alias (dev or prod)

`firebase use dev` or `firebase use prod`

3. Deploy cloud functions to respective project

`firebase deploy --only functions`

I feel like this is the naive and tedious way of doing this. Is there a better way of doing this where I can have a service-account-credentials-prod.json and a service-account-credentials-dev.json file in my functions directory, then depending on which project alias I'm using, it will know which service account credentials to deploy?

Would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction

Comment: Do you really need to deploy a service account with your functions? The Admin SDK and other Google SDKs can init with the default service account for your project, if you don't specify one, and that should be able to do everything you need.  This is the preferred way to do things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have two projects as well, development and production.

In `/functions` I have both files:

`/functions/production-cred.json` and

`/functions/development-cred.json`

I deploy using the respective commands:

`firebase deploy --only functions -P development` or

`firebase deploy --only functions -P production`.

In `index.js` I use the environment variable `process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT` to determine which environment is being used. This variable will contain the name of your project, which should be different between production and development, you cant print it to check.

Here's a sample:

```
const env = process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT
const development = (env == "myDevProject")
const database = development ? devDbUrl : prodDbUrl
const serviceAccountFile = development ? "devCred.json" : "prodCred.json"
const serviceAccount = require(`./${serviceAccountFile}`)
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: database
})
```

Doing it this way doesn't require you to set the alias with `firebase use dev|prod`. I used to do it the same way as you, and this improvement has made deploys faster and more reliable.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Because you do it this way, you have both service credential files in both cloud function deployments?

Comment: Yes. Might not be ideal, if you really need to upload them only to their respective environment, you could have a script that takes as input the environment to deploy and does the necessary work to keep one of them from being deployed.

And if my answer helped you, please mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Is there a way to import the service account file using an import statement in this case?