# Can't import ENV specific service account json file dynamically using Firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have two Firebase projects, and two service-accounts, so I am using (.env.dev, .env.prod)

I tried everything to import the service account path from .env.dev and .env.prod but nothing worked, I always have to comment and uncomment when deploying to a specific project, and it's painful and error-prone.

Need help !

```
// PROD
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert("./src/service-account.json"),
  storageBucket: "prod.storage.com"
});

// DEV
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert("./src/service-account-dev.json"),
  storageBucket: "dev.storage.com"
});
```

Comment: Please have a look at this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571158/deploying-different-service-account-credentials-json-file-to-different-cloud-fun) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655441/firebase-configuration-for-multiple-projects-environments)

Comment: You shouldn't use service account key file. And your issue will be solved!

Comment: Your function runs as the service account specified by the `--service-account=` flag when deploying the function. You don't need to use a service account key when it is deployed in GCP, just make sure it deploys as the required service account.